# horizontal flip animation on modal UIView

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, modal-dialog

how can i present a modal view with an horizontal flip animation (like pushing an view controller on a navigation controller) ?
i tried this but it doesn't work

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO]; 
[self presentModalViewController:detailsViewController animated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

thanks !

Answer (score 7):

This is all you need:

```
detailsViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
```